# missing python methods NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

Many of the methods which apparently come with NetworkX don't seem to be imported.  For example, according to the website, I should be able to use:

http://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.transitive_closure.html

the `transitive_closure()` method.

But when I run the python.py file,

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edges_from([
    ('a', 'c'),
    ('b', 'c'),
    ('c', 'd'),
])

C = nx.transitive_closure(G)
```

I get the error

```
C = nx.transitive_closure(G)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'transitive_closure'
```

Answer (score 1):

The command you're using appears to be new in the development version.  Here's the current documentation on the `dag` commands:

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms.dag.html

A straightforward solution: You can go to the documentation that you found (notice the "development" in the url).  Then copy and paste the commands from there into your version.  You can find where your version is by `help(nx.dag)`.  You'll need to remove some parts from the copy pasting that say "[doc]", you'll have to edit the `__all__` part, and you'll have to remove the `@not_implemented_for` command.